# Percona-xtrabackup hot backup issue with MyIsam Engine

Tags: percona, xtrabackup, innodb

We are running with the MyIsam Engine and Percona-xtrabackup is throwing the following error as the inndb engine is skipped [ my.cnf skip-innodb]. How could I resolve this issue with out enabling the inndb engine?

```
percona-xtrabackup-2.0.0/bin:# ./innobackupex-1.5.1 --user="root" --password=*** --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf" --socket=<path>/mysql.sock1  --ibbackup=<path>/percona-xtrabackup-2.0.0/bin/xtrabackup <path>/testbackup/
```

### **Percona Log :**

```
This software is published under
the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2, June 1991.

IMPORTANT: Please check that the backup run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful backup run innobackupex-1.5.1
           prints "completed OK!".

innobackupex-1.5.1: Using mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.57, for pc-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.1
innobackupex-1.5.1: Using mysql server version Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

innobackupex-1.5.1: Created backup directory <path>/testbackup/2012-06-08_16-55-23
120608 16:55:23  innobackupex-1.5.1: Starting mysql with options:  --defaults-file='/etc/my.cnf' --password=xxxxxxxx --user='root' --socket='/data/mysql1/mysql.sock1' --unbuffered --
120608 16:55:23  innobackupex-1.5.1: Connected to database with mysql child process (pid=25611)
120608 16:55:25  innobackupex-1.5.1: Connection to database server closed

120608 16:55:25  innobackupex-1.5.1: Starting ibbackup with command: <path>/percona-xtrabackup-2.0.0/bin/xtrabackup  --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf" --backup --suspend-at-end --target-dir=<path>/testbackup/2012-06-08_16-55-23
innobackupex-1.5.1: Waiting for ibbackup (pid=25618) to suspend
innobackupex-1.5.1: Suspend file '<path>/testbackup/2012-06-08_16-55-23/xtrabackup_suspended'

<path>/percona-xtrabackup-2.0.0/bin/xtrabackup version 2.0.0 for Percona Server 5.1.59 pc-linux-gnu (i686) (revision id: undefined)
xtrabackup: uses posix_fadvise().
xtrabackup: cd to /data/mysql1
xtrabackup: Target instance is assumed as followings.
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_home_dir = ./
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_file_size = 5242880
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
120608 16:55:26  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
xtrabackup: Something wrong with source files...
innobackupex-1.5.1: Error: ibbackup child process has died at ./innobackupex-1.5.1 line 371.
```

Answer (score 1):

is there a reason to use it? it will just lock the myiasm tables anyway for dump.  it is really a tool for innodb tables that can do myiasm but it locks them. Might as well just do a server wide lock and copy all the files.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make any sense to use `innobackupex` on a MyISAM-only installation. Here's why.

`innobackupex` is designed to create consistent backups from a running database; so-called "hot backups". This only works without interruption for InnoDB tablespaces as MyISAM requires you to perform a `READ LOCK` on the tables to be backed up consistently and this causes a disruption in the service as long as the lock isn't released.

The more MyISAM data you have, the more time `innobackupex` will have to lock your tables. Having MyISAM data only, it does not make sense to use the tool - it would be the same as

1. `mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`
2. `shell> cp -a /path/to/datadir/of/mysql /path/to-backup/dir`
3. when finished `mysql> UNLOCK TABLES`.

Whereas for InnoDB `innobackupex` just starts copying and then applies the transactionlog when preparing the update some time later (`--apply-log`), offline/independently.

Answer (score 0):

If you're resisting the change over to InnoDB because you think the process is difficult, here's what I use:

```
mysql -u root --password=<password> --database=db_name -B -N -e "SHOW TABLES" | awk '!/not_this_db/ && !/or_this_one/ && /^[a-z]/ {print "ALTER TABLE", $1, "ENGINE=INNODB;"}' | mysql -u root --password=<password> --database=db_name
```

You can exclude and include databases with the regex such as only dbs starting with a lowercase letter in my example above.

Of course the alters will lock the tables, but then you can use xtrabackup from there on out.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem when running innobackupex on a newly-created database with `skip-innodb` enabled.  It seems like innobackupex needs to have a functional InnoDB storage engine there, even if it isn't used, and it errors when trying to generate one for you.

After I started the database once with `#skip-innodb` commented out in my /etc/my.cnf (and I had to delete the ibdata1 file the backup script made, as it was corrupt), then shut it down and uncommented the `skip-innodb` line, the backup script worked as expected.

I would guess people don't run into this much anymore, as it is uncommon for someone to still be running MyISAM-only databases.